# SQL divide the column values to equal groups with ntile

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I need to write sql query that divide the products to 3 equal groups by their price, (The cheapest products will be in the first group). For each group I have to present the price ranges it includes and the average units in stock.

[image]

I try to use ntile but I got stuck:

```
SELECT UnitPrice, NTILE(3) OVER (
    ORDER BY UnitPrice ASC
) AS productGroup, UnitsInStock
FROM Products
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a query on top of this one.  Something like this:-

```
select productGroup, min(UnitPrice), max(UnitPrice), avg(UnitPrice)
from (
  SELECT UnitPrice, NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY UnitPrice ASC) AS productGroup
    , UnitsInStock
  FROM Products
) t1
group by productGroup
```